# Re-arrange Rows in UITableView; Save to Core Data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, edit

I have created a list of items in the UITableView, in which, after editing, like re-arranging the rows, when clicked on Done, the editing will stop and will show the changes.

When I leave the app and comes back again when re-launching the application, it should show the changed rows that has been changed previously, before closing application.

Also, I am actually using Core Data and wondering what is needed to it.

EXAMPLE (BEFORE):

- A
- B
- C

EXAMPLE (AFTER RE-ARRANGED):

- B
- C
- A

SHOULD APPEAR WHEN APP IS CLOSED AND LAUNCH:

- B
- C
- A

HOWEVER, IT SHOWS AS (LAST SAVED DATA):

- A
- B
- C

Here are my following codes:

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return YES;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
NSString *stringToMove = self.modules[sourceIndexPath.row];
[self.modules removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
[self.modules insertObject:stringToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];

}

-(IBAction)btnEdit:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

UIBarButtonItem * button = ((UIBarButtonItem*)sender);

if (!self.tableView.editing)
{
    [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    [button setTitle:@"Done"];
}

else
  {
    [button setTitle:@"Edit"];
    [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];

   }
}
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that self.modules are your items stored in core data, adding an order field would allow you to persist the order in which you can retrieve your objects later.

You would need to load your objects ordered by this new field then update it when user rearrange the order in editing mode.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to check where self.modules is getting set. 
Is the change you are making in the sequence persisted? 
If no, then this can only be achieved by - State Preservation and Restoration.